# Integrated graphics not working properly

Tags: drivers, xorg, intel-graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 in one of my systems and I've recently switched from an Nvidia graphic card to Intel's integrated chip on the processor. I'm running an Intel i9-13900K and there are a few things that make me think something is not installed correctly to use the integrated graphics.

1. First, I cannot change my resolution. It is currenly set to the
   proper resolution for my screen, but I have no options to change it
   in the settings. When I was running an Nvidia card I could change to
   any resolution. See the screenshot below.
2. When I play video files they are either choppy or have severe
   shearing/tearing effects. When I play videos through totem it is
   extremely choppy and unwatchable, and while VLC is much better it
   still has issues with video quality when at full screen and even
   sometimes at less then full screen.
3. Most importantly, when my screen turns off I have to turn the
   monitor off and back on again to get the video image to return.
   This is particularly annoying because I have my setup on a KVM and I
   switch between systems quite frequently. When I switch to another
   system and then back to this system on the KVM I have to physically
   turn off the monitor and turn it back on again every time. I also
   have to do this if the monitor blanks for power saving reasons due
   to inactivity. I can use the keyboard and mouse while the monitor is
   blank because there will be changes to my desktop which I can see
   after I power cycle the monitor and the image comes back.

[image: integrated video problem no res option]

None of the above problems occurred when I had a dedicated graphics card installed and going from a dedicated graphics card to integrated graphics has been the only change. I have removed all of the Nvidia drivers and packages and have restarted my system since switching. Below are the details of my system:

**System info:**

```
user@host1:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -E '(model name|flags)' | head -n 3
model name  : 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-13900K
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves avx_vnni dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req umip pku ospke waitpkg gfni vaes vpclmulqdq tme rdpid movdiri movdir64b fsrm md_clear serialize pconfig arch_lbr flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer posted_intr invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority apicv tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest vapic_reg vid ple shadow_vmcs ept_mode_based_exec tsc_scaling usr_wait_pause

user@host1:~$ uname -a
Linux host1 5.15.0-69-generic #76-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 17 17:19:29 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

user@host1:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

**Video details:**

```
user@host1:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6000000000-6000ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=3840,2160

user@host1:~$ sudo lspci -nn | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a780] (rev 04)

user@host1:~$ sudo lspci -vv | grep 00:02.0 -A 50
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device a780 (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device a780
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
    Region 0: Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 2: Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0
            ExtTag- RBE+ FLReset+
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop- FLReset-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis- NROPrPrP- LTR-
             10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt- EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR- OBFF Disabled,
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
        Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
        Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
        PASIDCap: Exec- Priv-, Max PASID Width: 14
        PASIDCtl: Enable- Exec- Priv-
    Capabilities: [200 v1] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        ATSCap: Invalidate Queue Depth: 00
        ATSCtl: Enable-, Smallest Translation Unit: 00
    Capabilities: [300 v1] Page Request Interface (PRI)
        PRICtl: Enable- Reset-
        PRISta: RF- UPRGI- Stopped+
        Page Request Capacity: 00008000, Page Request Allocation: 00000000
    Capabilities: [320 v1] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)
        IOVCap: Migration-, Interrupt Message Number: 000
        IOVCtl: Enable- Migration- Interrupt- MSE- ARIHierarchy-
        IOVSta: Migration-
        Initial VFs: 7, Total VFs: 7, Number of VFs: 0, Function Dependency Link: 00
        VF offset: 1, stride: 1, Device ID: a780
        Supported Page Size: 00000553, System Page Size: 00000001
        Region 0: Memory at 0000004010000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable)
        Region 2: Memory at 0000004020000000 (64-bit, prefetchable)
        VF Migration: offset: 00000000, BIR: 0

user@host1:~$ lsmod | grep video
video                  65536  1 i915
```

**Packages:**

```
user@host1:~$ dpkg -l | grep -Ei '(mesa|xorg)'
ii  libegl-mesa0:amd64                         22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- Mesa vendor library
ii  libegl-mesa0:i386                          22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  i386         free implementation of the EGL API -- Mesa vendor library
ii  libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64                     22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- development files
ii  libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64                      22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  amd64        transitional dummy package
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                      22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386                       22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                        22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglapi-mesa:i386                         22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  i386         free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                         9.0.2-1                                    amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64                     9.0.2-1                                    amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library -- development files
ii  libglx-mesa0:amd64                         22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  libglx-mesa0:i386                          22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  mesa-utils                                 8.4.0-1ubuntu1                             amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa utilities -- symlinks
ii  mesa-utils-bin:amd64                       8.4.0-1ubuntu1                             amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa utilities -- native applications
ii  mesa-va-drivers:amd64                      22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  amd64        Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-va-drivers:i386                       22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  i386         Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64                   22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  amd64        Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64                  22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  amd64        Mesa Vulkan graphics drivers
ii  mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386                   22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1                  i386         Mesa Vulkan graphics drivers
ii  python3-xkit                               0.5.0ubuntu5                               all          library for the manipulation of xorg.conf files (Python 3)
ii  xorg                                       1:7.7+23ubuntu2                            amd64        X.Org X Window System
ii  xorg-docs-core                             1:1.7.1-1.2                                all          Core documentation for the X.org X Window System
ii  xorg-sgml-doctools                         1:1.11-1.1                                 all          Common tools for building X.Org SGML documentation
ii  xserver-xorg                               1:7.7+23ubuntu2                            amd64        X.Org X server
ii  xserver-xorg-core                          2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1                amd64        Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-all                     1:7.7+23ubuntu2                            amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput                1.2.1-1                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-wacom                   1:1.0.0-3ubuntu1                           amd64        X.Org X server -- Wacom input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-legacy                        2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1                amd64        setuid root Xorg server wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all                     1:7.7+23ubuntu2                            amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                  22.0.0-1ubuntu0.1                          amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati                     1:19.1.0-2ubuntu1                          amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev                   1:0.5.0-2build1                            amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                   2:2.99.917+git20210115-1                   amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau                 1:1.0.17-2build1                           amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl                     0.1.5+git20200331-3                        amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon                  1:19.1.0-2ubuntu1                          amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa                    1:2.5.0-1build4                            amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware                  1:13.3.0-3build1                           amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
```

I have seen this in syslog but haven't really dug into the error yet. From my limited searching it seems to be just another symptom of the issue:

```
Apr 21 09:26:24 host1 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[9180]: (EE) event6  - HID 04d9:2013: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 26ms, your system is too slow
```

Also adding glxgears output:

```
jschaeffer@zipmaster07:~$ glxgears -info
GL_RENDERER   = llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits)
GL_VERSION    = 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.5
GL_VENDOR     = Mesa/X.org
GL_EXTENSIONS = GL_ARB_multisample GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_copy_texture GL_EXT_subtexture GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_texture GL_EXT_texture3D GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_multitexture GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_INGR_blend_func_separate GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_S3_s3tc GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_MESA_window_pos GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_window_pos GL_ATI_fragment_shader GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_NV_fog_distance GL_NV_half_float GL_APPLE_packed_pixels GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ATI_draw_buffers GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_read_format GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_timer_query GL_OES_EGL_image GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object GL_AMD_texture_texture4 GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_NV_conditional_render GL_AMD_conservative_depth GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_ARB_compatibility GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_tessellation_shader GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32 GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_NV_copy_image GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_ARB_draw_indirect GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_gpu_shader5 GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_shader_precision GL_ARB_shader_subroutine GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_ARB_viewport_array GL_EXT_direct_state_access GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_ARB_base_instance GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_AMD_query_buffer_object GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_compute_shader GL_ARB_copy_image GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_ARB_shader_image_size GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_ARB_stencil_texturing GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_query_levels GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_robustness GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_AMD_pinned_memory GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts GL_ARB_indirect_parameters GL_ARB_internalformat_query2 GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_query_buffer_object GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters GL_ARB_shader_group_vote GL_ARB_shading_language_include GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_texture_stencil8 GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility GL_ARB_clip_control GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted GL_ARB_cull_distance GL_ARB_derivative_control GL_ARB_direct_state_access GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples GL_ARB_texture_barrier GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64 GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile GL_ARB_post_depth_coverage GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops GL_ARB_shader_ballot GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array GL_ARB_texture_filter_minmax GL_EXT_texture_filter_minmax GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8 GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_RG8 GL_KHR_no_error GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d GL_ARB_gl_spirv GL_ARB_spirv_extensions GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_memory_object GL_EXT_memory_object_fd GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch_non_coherent GL_EXT_texture_shadow_lod GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y GL_EXT_EGL_sync 
VisualID 975, 0x3cf
29107 frames in 5.0 seconds = 5821.114 FPS
29694 frames in 5.0 seconds = 5933.936 FPS
28683 frames in 5.0 seconds = 5736.554 FPS
28935 frames in 5.0 seconds = 5786.897 FPS
27786 frames in 5.0 seconds = 5557.165 FPS
^C
```